# JavaScript onload Click event

Tags: javascript

I am working with the geolocation API and I am trying to set up an onclick event where once a button is clicked the longitude of a user's location is displayed. However my onclick function doesn't work because it seems like my function is loading even when i haven't invoked it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="style.css">
       <title>
       </title>
        <!--<script src="modernizr.custom.64298.js"></script>-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="showLocation()">Click</button>
        <p id="info"></p>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);

function showLocation(position) {
  var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "latitude: " + currPosLat;
}
```

I am just not sure what I am doing wrong. My latitude is just being loaded into my innerHTML without me even clicking. If I do use the click button it says coords is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code starts with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);`

This calls the showLocation function as soon as the .js is loaded which is why it runs immediately.

All you need to do is move this line to your onclick and it will work:

So your button becomes:

```
<button onclick="navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation)">Click</button>
```

and your script is just the showLocation function

```
function showLocation(position) {
    var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "latitude: " + currPosLat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff I will accept this comment in two minutes. Appreciate the help mate.

Comment: Thanks Jeff the newer method seems a lot more simplistic thanks mate.